# can't start unicorn using init.d service – can't find bundle as sudo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unix, capistrano, unicorn

I'm trying to set a rails test server, deployed using capistrano.

I know my capistrano scripts are working as it deploys to the production server using the same scripts without a problem.

During deployment, unicorn should be started, to do this

`sudo service unicorn_appname start`

is called.

This gives the following error:
`Job for unicorn_appname.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status unicorn_appname.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

When I check `sudo journalctl -u unicorn_appname` is see

```
systemd[1]: Starting LSB: starts the unicorn web server...
su[3790]: Successful su for user by root
su[3790]: + ??? root:user
su[3790]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user user by (uid=0)
unicorn_appname[3787]: -su: bundle: command not found
systemd[1]: unicorn_appname.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=127
systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: starts the unicorn web server.
systemd[1]: unicorn_appname.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd[1]: unicorn_appname.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

`/etc/init.d/unicorn_appname` exists and when in `/etc/init.d`

`./unicorn_appname start` works
`sudo ./unicorn_appname start` however gives `-su: bundle: command not found`

however `which bundle` and `sudo which bundle` both show the same path (`/home/user/.rbenv/shims/bundle`)

If possible I don't want to change the scripts, as they work on the other server.
So I think there's some setting different or missing on the new server – but I have no more idea where to look.

This is the content of `unicorn_appname`:

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          unicorn
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: starts the unicorn web server
# Description:       starts unicorn
### END INIT INFO

set -e

# Feel free to change any of the following variables for your app:
TIMEOUT=${TIMEOUT-60}
APP_ROOT=/home/user/apps/appname/current
PID_DIR=$APP_ROOT/tmp/pids
PID=$PID_DIR/unicorn.pid
CMD="cd $APP_ROOT; bundle exec unicorn -D -c /home/user/apps/appname/shared/config/unicorn.rb -E production"
AS_USER=user
set -u

OLD_PIN="$PID.oldbin"

sig () {
  test -s "$PID" && kill -$1 `cat $PID`
}

oldsig () {
  test -s $OLD_PIN && kill -$1 `cat $OLD_PIN`
}

workersig () {
  workerpid="$APP_ROOT/tmp/pids/unicorn.$2.pid"

  test -s "$workerpid" && kill -$1 `cat $workerpid`
}

run () {
  if [ "$(id -un)" = "$AS_USER" ]; then
    eval $1
  else
    su -c "$1" - $AS_USER
  fi
}

case "$1" in
start)
  sig 0 && echo >&2 "Already running" && exit 0
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
stop)
  sig QUIT && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Not running"
  ;;
force-stop)
  sig TERM && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Not running"
  ;;
kill_worker)
  workersig QUIT $2 && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Worker not running"
  ;;
restart|reload)
  sig USR2 && echo reloaded OK && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Couldn't reload, starting '$CMD' instead"
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
upgrade)
  if sig USR2 && sleep 2 && sig 0 && oldsig QUIT
  then
    n=$TIMEOUT
    while test -s $OLD_PIN && test $n -ge 0
    do
      printf '.' && sleep 1 && n=$(( $n - 1 ))
    done
    echo

    if test $n -lt 0 && test -s $OLD_PIN
    then
      echo >&2 "$OLD_PIN still exists after $TIMEOUT seconds"
      exit 1
    fi
    exit 0
  fi
  echo >&2 "Couldn't upgrade, starting '$CMD' instead"
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
reopen-logs)
  sig USR1
  ;;
*)
  echo >&2 "Usage: $0 <start|stop|restart|upgrade|force-stop|reopen-logs>"
  exit 1
  ;;
esac
```

Any more info you'll need?

## EDIT:

`user` is the user I use to deploy. For `root` on this system, nothing is installed. Can that be the problem?

Comment: I've never had to use any root privileges to deploy before so I don't think that's the issue (or it would flag on prod too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution:

On the prod server I had a `/etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh` that's missing on the new server.

That's its content:

```
export RBENV_ROOT=/home/user/.rbenv
export PATH=$RBENV_ROOT/shims:$RBENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: also found this question, which had the same answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31971806/unicorn-service-upstart-script-throws-su-bundle-command-not-found?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem (may) be:

```
cd $APP_ROOT; bundle exec unicorn -D -c /home/user/apps/appname/shared/config/unicorn.rb -E production"
```

Assuming that is the same command you're using on your test server, you'll need to change the environment to test.

Comment: I know what you see, but that's not the problem. I have the environment correctly set.